# My JTable throws a classCastException. I am loading from a text file and need the (True/false) column to show as Checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable, boolean-expression

Anyone help me out. I am new to Java and loading table data from a text-file.
Here is my Table data:

- Log1, Subject, name, pet-name, time, true, date, false
- Log2, Subject, name, pet-name, time, true, date, false
- Log3, Subject, name, pet-name, time, true, date, false
- Log4, Subject, name, pet-name, time, true, date, false
- Log5, Subject, name, pet-name, time, true, date, false

And here is the java program I am using to set it on the table:

```
public class SubjectTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private String[] Titles = new String[]{ "LOG", "SUBJECT", "NAME", "OWNER-NAME", "TIME","OWNER", "DATE", "BORROWED"};

static File pwd = new File("columnVals");
int linenumber;
Vector data;
Vector columns;

public SubjectTableModel(){
    String line;
    data = new Vector();
    //columns = new Vector();

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pwd);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), ", ");
        /*while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
                columns.addElement(st1.nextToken());*/
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(line, ", ");
                while (st2.hasMoreTokens())
                        data.addElement(st2.nextToken());
        }
        br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return Titles[column];
}

public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    switch(columnIndex){
case 0:
    return String.class;
case 1:
    return String.class;
case 2:
    return String.class;
case 3:
    return String.class;
case 4:
    return String.class;
case 5:
    return Boolean.class;
case 6:
    return String.class;
case 7:
    return Boolean.class;
default:
    return null;
}
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return 8;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size() / getColumnCount();

}

public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
            + columnIndex);

}
}
```

The exception thrown when I run it is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
at javax.swing.JTable$BooleanRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(Unknown Source)...
```

IMPORTANT TO NOTE: Without the `getColumnClass` method, everything runs fine.

Comment: I have to add that I need this CheckBox to be clickable so I can add Listeners to it. I need it to be able to enter data into another text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define Boolean.class to be returned for some columns but your model contains Strings.

You can change your `getValueAt()` method to return booleans for the columns. Like this

```
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex==5 || columnIndex==7) {
    return Boolean.valueOf((String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
            + columnIndex));
    }
    return (String) data.elementAt((rowIndex * getColumnCount())
            + columnIndex);

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. It worked but it is not clickable. Is there a way to add listeners to it and make it clickable?
If it is not clickable, it is not useful.

Comment: @user3554512 To make them editable you need to override `isCellEditable` to return true for that column and the `setValueAt` method so you can modify the data that the `getValueAt` uses.

Comment: This also help, thanks - but how do I enter "setValueAt" true/false into the particular location in the text file? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @user3554512 Write "@DSquare" so I get notified about your response. What do you mean file? `getValueAt` does not read from a file it reads from a data structure in memory (in your case `Vector data`). Modify that data structure to hold the new values. If you want, you can save those changes in a file later, but that is unrelated.